# Find an example of a function that sustains the following terms:

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, derivatives

It can happen that $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}f(x_0 + th)$ exists for all h but is
not linear in h. Give an example.

So of course, such $f$ cannot be differentiable at $x_0$. I wanted to try something with $cos$ and $sin$, but I didn't really find anything that sustains the terms above.

Comment: Is $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: $f:\mathbb{R}^n-->\mathbb{R}^m$, from my understanding of the question you need to give an example of f so you can define f as you wish..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
    f(x_1,x_2) = \begin{cases}
        x_1  & \text{if $|x_2| \geq |x_1|$} \\
        -x_1 & \text{if $|x_2| < |x_1|$} \\
    \end{cases}
$$
Then 
$$
    \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(th_1,th_2)}{t} 
    = \begin{cases} 
         h_1 & \text{if $|h_2| \geq |h_1|$}\\
        -h_1 & \text{if $|h_2| < |h_1|$}\\
      \end{cases}
$$